# Ranking data with views

Tags: sql, view

I have two tables that I'm working with.  FILMS and STUDIO.  I'm trying to make a view that sums the profit of films by studio.

Here are my tables:

```
**FILMS**
FILM_ID       NUMBER
FILM_NAME     VARCHAR2
FILM_DIRECTOR VARCHAR2

**STUDIO**
STUDIO_ID    NUMBER
STUDIO_NAME  VARCHAR2
PROFIT       NUMBER
```

I have been trying to make a view with the following columns, STUDIO_ID,    STUDIO_NAME, TOTAL_PROFIT.
Where TOTAL_PROFIT holds the sum.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
        STUDIO.STUDIO_ID,
        FILMS.PROFIT
    FROM
        STUDIO,
        FILMS
    WHERE
        STUDIO.STUDIO_ID IS NOT NULL
```

I'm not sure how to store the sum of profit by studio in another new column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no connection between FILMS and STUDIO. The FILMS table does not contain a PROFIT column. Are you sure this is the situation? Because if it is it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

use sum aggregate funtionc

```
    SELECT
    STUDIO.STUDIO_ID,STUDIO_NAME
    sum(FILMS.PROFIT) as totalprofit
FROM
    STUDIO,
    FILMS
WHERE
    STUDIO.STUDIO_ID IS NOT NULL
 group by STUDIO.STUDIO_ID,STUDIO_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is to join the two columns with cross join,but instead you need to do something like this.

```
SELECT
STUDIO.STUDIO_ID,STUDIO_NAME
sum(PROFIT) as TOTAL_PROFIT
FROM
STUDIO
WHERE
STUDIO.STUDIO_ID IS NOT NULL
group by STUDIO.STUDIO_ID,STUDIO_NAME
```

Hope this helps.